# jquery noconflict breaks some of the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this question has been asked earlier, I've looked and can't solve my problem with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

when I insert this code, the "jquery-latest.min.js" stops working

this are the line that are in conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

I may be me putting the code in the wrong place...

Comment: Please show us in which order you put these three scripts.

Comment: Wait, you're including two different versions of jQuery in the same page?

Comment: You have to go through the changelog with the latest jQuery version. See those and update your scripts accordingly. One more thing try adding one more library which is migrate provided for using older ones with latest jquery.

Comment: @j08691 its an old page, and its using a javascript function using that lib, when I remove the oldest one, that javascript stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `migrate`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

#### and remove the older one.

### From the docs:

#### jQuery Migrate plugin

> We have created the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify the transition from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later. Use the uncompressed development version to diagnose compatiblity issues, it will generate warnings on the console that you can use to identify and fix problems. Use the compressed production version to simply fix compatibility issues without generating console warnings.

[Read More Here](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: Interesting, never heard of migrate

Comment: @RicardoAlves Remember that this should not be a final solution. This should be used to help you upgrade your code

Comment: @Juan Mendes agreed (Both thumbs up)

Answer (score 5):

You only need one reference to jquery. 1.4.2 is a very old version, is there a reason you are including that version as well as the latest version?

Remove one of your references and you're done.

Comment: @RicardoAlves You cannot load two versions of jQuery at the same time. You have to fix the calls to the old deprecated jQuery code.

Comment: @RicardoAlves The suggestion from Jai should help you a lot in migrating your code